# Persistent partition for Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

First, I'm sorry for my poor English.
I'm windows user and i want to try to use ubuntu withou install it.
I know that we can use ext2 partition with label casper-rw to store data on it.
But i have a question about this partition.
If i want to try other version of Ubuntu, also want to store its data, then i must create 2nd ext2 casper-rw partition? Or I can use old one that i create before?
If i must create new ext2 partition, then how each version use this partition because it has same label ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution to multiple persistent partitions for many years now, without success. Multiple persistent casper-rw files can be used by adding the persistent-path to grub.cfg right after persistent, ie persistent-path=/foldername/

If you reuse a persistent partition for a different version of Ubuntu, without first deleting the data in it, you will end up with a total mess and it will probably not boot.

Just open the casper-rw partition using "sudo nautilus" and delete the data in it and the new version should run persistent fine.

You can also make a second persistent partition labeled home-rw it will store the home folder and it is usable from version to version.

You can make multiple casper-rw partitions, however Ubuntu always seems to use the one with the lowest number ie sda4 not sda5.

You do know that currently, (16.04), syslinux type installs, (Rufus, UNetbootin, SDC, Universal) do not work with persistent partitions. You need a grub2 installer like **mkusb** to use persistent partitions.